# What is the 'rdt' object in the error: 'KeyError: "Unable to open object (Object 'rdt' doesn't exist)"?

Tags: python, h5py, keyerror

I am trying to execute the following code

```
impot spacepy.time as spt
import spacepy.omni as om
ticks = spt.Ticktock(['2002-02-02T12:00:00', '2002-02-02T12:10:00'],     'ISO')
d = om.get_omni(ticks)
d.tree(levels=1)
```

that is the example at the spacepy documentation.

I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-28-bd1a52c0010b>", line 1, in <module>
data = om.get_omni(ticks)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacepy-0.1.6-py2.7.egg/spacepy/omni.py", line 252, in get_omni
enval, stval = omnirange(dbase=ldb)[1], omnirange(dbase=ldb)[0]

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spacepy-0.1.6-py2.7.egg/spacepy/omni.py", line 377, in omnirange
start, end = hfile['RDT'][0], hfile['RDT'][-1]

File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip-4rPeHA-build/h5py/_objects.c:2684)

File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip-4rPeHA-build/h5py/_objects.c:2642)

File "~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py", line 166, in __getitem__
oid = h5o.open(self.id, self._e(name), lapl=self._lapl)

File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip-4rPeHA-build/h5py/_objects.c:2684)

File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (/tmp/pip-4rPeHA-build/h5py/_objects.c:2642)

File "h5py/h5o.pyx", line 190, in h5py.h5o.open (/tmp/pip-4rPeHA-build/h5py/h5o.c:3570)

KeyError: "Unable to open object (Object 'rdt' doesn't exist)"
```

I don't know how to fix this.

The same problem occur when executing other SpacePy codes.

Comment: How did you install SpacePy?

Comment: There is an tutorial to install: [link](https://pythonhosted.org/SpacePy/install_linux.html) 

If you have installed all the dependencies, is just to install with:

    pip install spacepy

Comment: It looks like `get_omni` is trying to fetch a data series names `rdt` (or `RDT`) from a `hdf5` file, and that data series does not exist on the file it uses.  You'll need to study `spacepy` documentation more carefully.

Comment: Did you figure this out I'm having the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you run SpacePy for the first time, a special dataset of OMNI data (more details on it [here](https://pythonhosted.org/SpacePy/omni.html)) needs to be downloaded. To obtain it, simply execute:

```
import spacepy
spacepy.toolbox.update()
```

For this function to work properly, you have to make sure that all dependencies according to the [Installation Guideline](https://pythonhosted.org/SpacePy/install.html) are met - especially the [NASA CDF library](http://cdf.gsfc.nasa.gov/) is needed.